# Read from /dev/input/event

Tags: c, linux, events, ubuntu, input

I use evtest in a virtualbox to get mouse position.

By reading from event3 (Generic Explorer Mouse) I only get mouseclicks and wheel events.
By reading from event5 (VirtualBox mouse integration) I only get the absolute values of the mouse position.

When opening event3 with evtest it tells me that it can read the following:

Event type 1(EV_KEY)
 Mouse Buttons
Event type 2(EV_REL)
 REL_X
 REL_Y
 Wheel

But the relative coordinates didnt get reported. 
Is this a problem from virtualBox or a general problem?

Could someone not running on a virtual machine test this please?

I need that relative moves.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's how VirtualBox reports mouse events by default. If you want relative mouse events, change the pointing device to "PS/2 Mouse" (under the VM settings, in the Display section).